# Why isn't java.text.Normalizer available for my Android app?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android app and in Eclipse, `java.text.Normalizer` can't be imported. It's like Eclipse can't find it. I saw another SO question asking about `Normalizer` alternatives to Android apps that are < version 2.3. Is the class limited only to certain Android SDK versions?

Comment: It was added in 2.3, but it seemed to be available in 2.2 anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185332/why-is-java-text-normalizer-available-on-my-android-2-2-phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - they only added it in 2.3, see the top right corner of the [developer docs page](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Normalizer.html) on Normalizer where it says "Since: API Level 9."

Comment: Ahhhh... for some reason I thought since it was `java.text.*` that mean't it wasn't apart of core Android. Thank you.

Comment: How come I see it discussed on so many random Java websites that don't appear to have anything to do with Android development?

Comment: It's a standard Java class, but since Android isn't a standard Java environment they can pick and choose which standard classes they want to support. There are a number of them they still don't support, and a number of them that they only added support for recently; every new class means a slightly bigger OS (= more flash memory usage) not to mention additional testing to make sure it's not broken by every new Android update.

Answer (score 1):

It is Availible at API 9. Make sure that you are using the correct API settings in the properties of your app in eclispe.